# How do I white list apps in AdGuard?

Tags: ipad, adblock

I use the DNS ad blocker AdGuard on my iPad which is nice but, some apps don’t work as intended when being blocked. I’d like to white list one of the games I play (Crossy Road.) How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume this is about the DNS filter within AdGuard. The [manual page](https://kb.adguard.com/en/ios/overview#dns-protection) doesn’t mention whitelisting of apps. Not sure this even is possible, the DNS probably doesn‘t even know which app is trying to resolve a name. So disabling it while playing Crossy Road might be the best option here.